# TypeScript jQuery type definition

Tags: jquery, typescript, type-definition

I am converting a sample app from TypeScript 2.3 to 2.4, and from jQuery 3.1.1 to 3.2.1 (clearly using the latest type definition).

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es5",
            "scripthost",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "strict": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
    ]
}
```

(I have added the lib as described in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17239)

And here is my packages.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "asp.net",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "3.2.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "*"
    }
}
```

Now: I expect that in a TypeScript file, if I use $, I should get Intellisense and so on. But instead I get a compile error.

Please note:
- I'm using VS2017 15.2 with the latest TypeScript 2.4.1.0 plugin
- I don't want to use ES6 yet

What should I change?

Comment: as for me - nearly everything. You don't even have `typescript` in your dependencies - how are you supposed to compile the project? And as I understand the main issue now is that you did not run `npm install`. Ideally, you should migrate the whole project to npm or vice versa

Comment: That's `package.json`, not `packages.json`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the new Visual Studio plugin (version 2.4.1.0).
The solution compiles ok from command line.